# Using variables of one class in another class JAVA

Tags: java, class

I'm new to java and i couldn't understand it properly. How should i use variables of one class in another class

**Example:** I need a program to add 2 numbers. I want to have an input class that takes input and the main method in other class should use the variables from input class to perform addition.
this is totally wrong how to correct?

[image: this wrong]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: i edit my answer @sai kiran you can check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another answer:

**Class add**

```
public class add {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ans;
        input in = new input();
        //here you can set value at a and b to the other class
        in.readAandB();

        //now you get make your operation
        ans = in.a + in.b;
        System.out.println("result = " + ans);
    }
}
```

**Class input**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class input {

    //declaration of your attribute
    public int a;
    public int b;

    //constructor of your class input
    public input(){
    }

    //function to put values in your attribute a and b
    public void readAandB(){
        //You can use scanner to init your values
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a :");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter b :");
        b = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,thanks exactly what i have been trying from 3hrs.

Comment: No explanation of global variables and Scanner. Nice

Comment: you can check now @RafiduzzamanSonnet, if you want to add some explanation it will be my happy for that :)

Comment: From OP's code, it is clear that OP doesn't know about scope of variables and global variables. Why have you declared the variables globally (outside the constructor) ? Why does it not work when declared inside the constructor? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example:

**Class B**

```
public class B {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    //constrictor of my class
    public B(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int addition(){
        //return the addition of x and y
        return this.x + this.y;
    }
}
```

**Class A**

```
public class A {

    //main methode
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b;
        //You can use scanner to get values
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number:");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Number:");
        b = in.nextInt();

        //create a new object, and give it the values you want
        B b = new B(a, b);
        //print the result
        System.out.println("addition = " + b.addition());
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

And you can learn about classes and constructor and methodes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: see i added pics ,i know i am totally wrong but can i correct it or should i use totally a different method

Comment: can explain to me what you want exactly? do you want to call a method in another class that return a result of addition or what exactly?.

Comment: @sai kiran check my second answer i think this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object of the input class in the other class where your main method resides and access variables of input class by objname.variablename

Comment: what if they are private ? you can't access them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Take two classes, A & B.
As i understood what you need is to access variables in A inside B's main method.
To do this you have two approaches. One is as described by @MrLY in the above answer. I recommend to use that but there is some other way too.

I'm not going to give you the exact coding since it is better to find the way to find codes by your self.

1. In class A set your variables as public. ( public variables are accessible from any where within the project) say variable 1 & variable2.
2. Create a Object of Class A in the main method of Class B.(  eg: A a = new A() )
3. now you can access the two variables by simply calling to the variable through its instance. ( eg. if need to assign value to variable1 ;

a.variable1="value to assign" )

It's quite simple.

REPEAT it's better to use the approach suggested by @MrLY . The reason is it gives you encapsulation of your data. Since if then you can decide where to use and when to use your variables.

Take a look at [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)  It will give you some idea about access modifiers in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think so the above said approaches are correct i am also going to share something with u hope it helps u

```
package shivamprojects;

public class addition {
public int a;
public int b;
public addition(int a,int b) {
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
}
public void ppr() {
    System.out.println(a+b);
}

}




add class

package shivamprojects;
public class add {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
addition a=new addition(1,2);
a.a=25;
a.b=30;
a.ppr();
}

}
```

in both the classes in the very first i have just declared variables a and b as public and in add class i assigned the values hope it helps u